# Need to get ArrayList() to Export to Excel

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, excel-2010

I am having trouble exporting my data to excel. my application uses an ArrayList() to house the data.  I don't completely understand arraylist's.  Inside my ArrayList() is a MyDataClass, then the Val1, Val2, etc...The array has 7 columns and can have anywhere from 1 to 300 rows of data.  When I do this, I can't seem to get down to the Val1 data, my excel sheet in cell A1 is saying, MyDataClass.
Can someone please help me with this, thank you in advance. I am on visual studio 2010 and Office 2010.

```
Protected Sub btnExport_Click_Backup(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click

    Dim ItemList As New ArrayList()
    ItemList = Session("sessItemList2")
    ItemList.Reverse()


    Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("SerlNmbr")
    dt.Columns.Add("ItemNmbr")
    dt.Columns.Add("LocnCode")
    dt.Columns.Add("Status")
    dt.Columns.Add("MSL")
    dt.Columns.Add("InvoiceNumber")
    dt.Columns.Add("ActivationStatus")
```

'  THIS IS WHERE I AM DOING SOMETHING WRONG...

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To ItemList.Count - 1

        Dim dr As DataRow

        dr = dt.NewRow

        dr.Item(0) = ItemList(0).Val1.ToString

        dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    Next

    Try
        Dim oExcel As Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim oBook As Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Worksheet
        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
        oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
        Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
        Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

        'Export the Columns to excel file
        For Each dc In dt.Columns
            colIndex = colIndex + 1
            oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
        Next

        'Export the rows to excel file
        For Each dr In dt.Rows
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
            colIndex = 0
            For Each dc In dt.Columns
                colIndex = colIndex + 1
                oSheet.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
            Next
        Next

        'Set final path
        Dim fileName As String = "c:\temp\ExportedFile" + ".xls"
        Dim finalPath = fileName
        oSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
        'Save file in final path
        oBook.SaveAs(finalPath, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)



        'Release the objects
        ReleaseObject(oSheet)
        oBook.Close(False, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
        ReleaseObject(oBook)
        oExcel.Quit()
        ReleaseObject(oExcel)
        'Some time Office application does not quit after automation: so i am calling GC.Collect method.
        GC.Collect()


        '  Open the file for the user
        Dim oxcel As Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim owb As Workbook
        Dim osht As Worksheet
        Dim ocell As Range

        oxcel = New Interop.Excel.Application
        oxcel.Visible = True

        ' my cpu errors out here becz my Office is not registered, you can go to excel & remove Registration Msgbox then press continue
        owb = oxcel.Workbooks.Open(finalPath)
        osht = owb.Worksheets(1)
        ocell = osht.Range("A1")
    Catch ex As Exception
        '  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        '  Need an error
    End Try

End Sub
```

'  here is a small portion of the MyDataClass

Public Class MyDataClass

```
Public Sub New(ByVal v1 As String, ByVal v2 As String, ByVal v3 As String, ByVal v4 As String, Optional ByVal v5 As String = "", Optional ByVal v6 As String = "", Optional ByVal v7 As String = "", Optional ByVal v8 As String = "")
    Val1 = v1
    Val2 = v2
    Val3 = v3
    Val4 = v4
    Val5 = v5
    Val6 = v6
    Val7 = v7
    Val8 = v8
End Sub
Public Property Val1() As String
    Get
        Return _Val1
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Val1 = value
    End Set
End Property
```

etc...

```
Public _Val1 As String
Public _Val2 As String
Public _Val3 As String
Public _Val4 As String
Public _Val5 As String
Public _Val6 As String
Public _Val7 As String
Public _Val8 As String
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList is a list of objects. There is no .Val property on it. There may be an object there with a val property, but first you have to cast it.

You didn't actually show us how you make the arraylist, or what it contains so I have to guess.

If you have a class with Val1 as a property, you have to cast it to that object type before you can access val1

```
dr.Item(0) = Cast(ItemList(0),MyClass).Val1.ToString
```

Since an ArrayList just takes object, you have to cast them to their appropriate type first. Or, if you just needs strings you can just call ToString on simple types like integers.

FYI, if you are working with Excel in a .Net application understand that you will need Excel on the server. You also won't have permissions to access it by default and Microsoft has recommended against doing this for over a decade. There are third-party .Net components designed to work with the various office file formats without requiring office installed. The threading model of the office apps is completely wrong for being used in a web environment.

Comment: '  here is where MyDataClass is created earlier in the program.
Dim data As MyDataClass = New MyDataClass(strEsn, strItemId, strLocnCode, strStatus, strMSL, strInvoiceNumber, strActivationStatus)

' Then its later added here:

 ItemList.Add(data)

Comment: I added the code for the MyDataClass at the top of the webpage

Comment: I tried your line of code and am getting this error for:  dr.Item(0) = Cast(ItemList(0), "MyDataClass").Val1.ToString.   -- Too few type arguments for Systems.Activities.Expressions

Comment: Don't use quotes around MyDataClass. It's expecting a class and not a string.

dr.Item(0) = Cast(ItemList(0), MyDataClass).Val1.ToString

Comment: Also, if you use namespaces you'll need the fully qualified class such as 
MyNamespace.MyDataClass

Comment: I am trying this and its not working. What do I put for the MyNameSpace?    this is what I put and it didn't work:    dr.Item(0) = Cast(ItemList(0), MyDataClass).Val1.ToString

Comment: I tried this and it took away the squiggly line under the MyDataClass, but it still has the squiggly line under Cast:    dr.Item(0) = Cast(ItemList(0), MyDataClass.Val1).Val1.ToString

Comment: The MyDataClass is on a separate .vb file called MyDataClass.vb from where the export to excel is taking place, if that helps at all and its in a different folder called App_Code